# opencv Hough Circles 'overload resolution failed'

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

```
i = cv2.imread('./folder/image.png')
i = cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(i,cv2.HoughCircles,1.2,100)
print(circles)
```

Whenever I try to run the above code I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.....\Main.py", line 112, in <module>
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(i,cv2.HoughCircles,1,20)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'HoughCircles'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Argument 'method' is required to be an integer
>  - Argument 'method' is required to be an integer
```

Comment: Check out official docs for [HoughCircles function here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d). And there is a [nice tutorial for Python here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html). Probably you want to change your argument `cv2.HoughCircles` to a valid HoughModes. They use cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Your calling args are wrong. Read the doc.

```py
cv2.HoughCircles(   image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]] ) ->    circles
'''
    image: The input image.
    method: Detection method.
    dp: the Inverse ratio of accumulator resolution and image resolution.
    mindst: minimum distance between centers of detected circles.
    param_1 and param_2: These are method specific parameters.
    min_Radius: minimum radius of the circle to be detected.
    max_Radius: maximum radius to be detected. 
'''
```